# How do I properly format this multipart email?

Tags: email, format, multipart

I'm having a real hard time formatting a multipart email, which results in a blank document being shown by any mail program I view it in.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Sorry if this has been answered before... I tried a few other people's answers, but haven't been able to tie any fix to my problem.

Thanks ahead!

```
Delivered-To: omenjohn@gmail.com
Received: by 10.182.151.107 with SMTP id up11csp166588obb;
        Fri, 22 Feb 2013 04:03:14 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.50.53.208 with SMTP id d16mr804024igp.5.1361534594250;
        Fri, 22 Feb 2013 04:03:14 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <noreply@lab.dyndnds-ip.com>
Received: from smtp-out-02.shaw.ca (smtp-out-02.shaw.ca. [64.59.136.138])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id xf7si2720052igb.40.2013.02.22.04.03.14;
        Fri, 22 Feb 2013 04:03:14 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 64.59.136.138 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of noreply@lab.dyndnds-ip.com) client-ip=64.59.136.138;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 64.59.136.138 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of noreply@lab.dyndnds-ip.com) smtp.mail=noreply@lab.dyndnds-ip.com
X-Cloudmark-SP-Filtered: true
X-Cloudmark-SP-Result: v=1.1 cv=3f4U5fHrZLLPCzJ96ldNbjtja1zQ0ih230F6vdsLr5s= c=1 sm=1
 a=FaKJ9xKj03AA:10 a=BLceEmwcHowA:10 a=A_tRFZU-kTUA:10
 a=KDKwGF1bB4N2lZfoIKkULA==:17 a=wN4yYl2XIkzaJHmYasIA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10
 a=CSdORdO7lnbvznqBb-0A:9 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=MZpOI37Du90A:10
 a=HpAAvcLHHh0Zw7uRqdWCyQ==:117
Received: from unknown (HELO lab.dyndns-ip.com) ([24.77.8.238])
  by smtp-out-02.shaw.ca with SMTP; 22 Feb 2013 05:03:13 -0700
Received: from Danielle-PC ([127.0.0.1])
    by lab.dyndns-ip.com
    ; Fri, 22 Feb 2013 06:02:53 -0600
Message-ID: <04371205-4ED3-48B2-BDA8-A338DBCAE3D1@lab.dyndns-ip.com>
Subject: Automated Email
To: 
From: Structure Agency <no-reply@lab.dyndns-ip.com>
Return-Path: Structure Agency <no-reply@lab.dyndns-ip.com>
Sender: Structure Agency <no-reply@lab.dyndns-ip.com>
Content-Language: en
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Fri, 22 Feb 2013 06:02:53 -0600
Priority: normal
Importance: normal
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alt-boundary-1I6GTFY8"


--alt-boundary-1I6GTFY8
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Plain text message!

--alt-boundary-1I6GTFY8
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Automated Email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Message in HTML!</p>
    </body>
</html>


--alt-boundary-1I6GTFY8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure that the last boundary needs "--" adding to the end.

Hope that helps,
Stuart